# Нативное подключение к ssh C#

Tags: c#, mysql, ssh

Как подключится к ssh с помощью C# без использования сторонних библиотек?
Нужно просто подключится по ssh к серверу и выполнить команду.
Использование сторонних библиотек запрещено системой.
Есть ли нативный способ для этого?

Самый лучший вариант этот просто использовать plink из пакета putty.

Пример кода подключения ssh и получение списка баз данных mysql

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Process plink = new Process();
        plink.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
        plink.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        plink.StartInfo.ErrorDialog = false;
        plink.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        plink.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        plink.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        plink.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

        string ipAddr = "";
        string userLogin = "";
        string userPass = "";

        plink.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("-ssh {0} -l {1} -pw {2}", ipAddr, userLogin, userPass);
        plink.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Program Files\\PuTTY\\plink.exe";

        plink.Start();

        ReadStream(plink.StandardOutput);
        ReadStream(plink.StandardError);

        string MysqlUser = "";
        string MysqlPass = "";
        plink.StandardInput.WriteLine(string.Format("mysql -u {0} -p\"{1}\"", MysqlUser, MysqlPass));
        plink.StandardInput.WriteLine("show databases;");
        plink.StandardInput.WriteLine("exit;");
        plink.StandardInput.Close();

    }

    private static void ReadStream(StreamReader reader)
    {
        new Thread(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                int current;
                while ((current = reader.Read()) >= 0)
                    Console.Write((char)current);
            }
        }).Start();
    }

}
```

Comment: "Использование сторонних библиотек запрещено системой. Есть ли нативный способ для этого?" - к сожалению нет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Использование сторонних библиотек запрещено системой. Есть ли нативный способ для этого?

Нет.

SSH - это технология для удалённого взаимодействия из мира *nix. А, .NET стал кроссплатформенным сравнительно недавно и многое в нём ещё не поддерживается из коробки.

Поэтому без дополнительных библиотек (например, [SSH.NET](https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET)) не обойтись.

Альтернативный вариант. Взять консольный SSHrkbtyn (например plink из пакета putty) и попробовать запустить его в туннельном режиме. Но, это всё равно не коробочный вариант.